# Lists and MySQL queries

Tags: sql, mysql, list

Would it be possible to run a MySQL query pulling the names of locations from a table, inserting them into a dropdown menu and then automatically generating a URL for each one  e.g.  `blablabla.bla/index.php?location=blablabla` every time the page loads?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I doubt someone is going to do it for you. You're basically asking us to write the start of a web application.

Comment: Actually, I was asking someone to point me in the right direction, I didn't ask anyone to code it for me, just to tell me if it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you would just run the query, parse the results through a loop in which you would build your links from the returned values -- concatenating the result text to the other portion of your links.

```
<select name='locations'>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['location']."'>".$row['location']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Ah, ok. That helps a lot, I'm still new to PHP and SQL so I will probably have more questions in the future lol. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 But be sure to escape output with htmentities(). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting